# How to make this unfolding anime

Tags: animation

do you know how I can make this unfolding anime?
Should I do with shape keys or armature?
The mesh is imported from 3D max, so it is not clean. Please see the attachment below.

Thanks for your time!

There is a video. https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7n4a.jpg

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to animate?

Comment: @vklidu the animation is in the video. I want to fold it then unfold it.

Comment: I saw the animation, but it is not clear for me (probably my English) if you just want to open the hard plastic parts or also to stretch the rubber part like in the video, that is quite hard for me to imagine how to animate something like this and also even without hands that manipulates with object. Whole animation like this without hands will looks weird I think.

Comment: The part of pulling out the hard plastic part is easy. I am having trouble making the rubber part fold and unfold. It is just a product feature demo, no human involved is ok. haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick try with bones, I guess it's the right solution, but you'll probably need to clean the topology:

[image]

Comment: I probably need to retopology this part. Thank you! @moonboots